# Fetch data in VB.NET from online MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, vb.net, wordpress

I have a VB.NET app created in VS 2012. All right. My app have multiple forms but the user needs to login first into first form to be able to read any others.

I have a server (on the internet) and I installed Wordpress. 
Now, I need to make my app to fetch username and password from wordpres's database (I know the server, name, username and password of the database). If the name and password written by the user in textboxes of the app matches one of users from Wordpress database, then the user should be able to see them other forms.
My problem is that I don't know very good to code database connections.
Can anyone help me?

This is what I did but doesn't seem to work

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Imports MySql.Data

Public Class Update_page
    Public dset As New System.Data.DataSet
    Public strSQL As String
    Public cmd As New MySqlCommand
    As Dreader Public MySqlDataReader
       As New MySqlConnection Public sConnection
    Update_Load Private Sub (ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        If sConnection.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
             sConnection.ConnectionString = "SERVER = my_server; USERID =My_id; PASSWORD = My_password; DATABASE = u3802032254;"
            sConnection.Open ()
            'MessageBox.Show ("Connected to server")
        Else
            'Catch ex As MySqlException
            MessageBox.Show ("Not connected to server")
            'End Try
        End If
       USER ()
     End Sub

        Public Sub USER ()
            Dim da As New MySqlDataAdapter
            Dim ds As New DataSet
            dset.EnforceConstraints = False
            strSQL = "SELECT user FROM wp_users"
            cmd = New MySqlCommand ()
            cmd.CommandText = strSQL
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            cmd.Connection = sConnection
            ds = New DataSet ()
            da.SelectCommand = cmd
            da.Fill (ds, "User")
            Titulo_combo.DataSource = ds.Tables (0)
            Titulo_combo.DisplayMember = "Title"
        End Sub
```

Comment: Please post the exact error mesage, it would help us to help you

Comment: Well, it simply doesn't connect.

Comment: Try this format: "Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;"

Comment: "Unhandled Exception" then it freezes the whole app.

Comment: Can you please give me an example of mysql connection in VB.net? Maybe I miss something

Comment: The example I posted is valid for .net. You can see for yourself in the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming-connecting-connection-string.html). Your issue may be related to something else.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your server accepts external connections to the MySQL Database?
Most free Database hosts do not support the external access. Is it a paid or free hosting?

Comment: Paid, yep. It does because I have a special windows with required ports, pass and address.